# why group in pig has odd order behavier

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

In hadoop if you want to group and order something and you write java , the result is that group keys will also be sort defaultly by Lexicographical order,all done with one MR job, so that you spare the another order job.

But now I join using Pig , find a quirky thing.

My input (test.txt) is:

```
a  
ab   
abc  
b     
c
```

My script is:

```
A=load 'test.txt' as c1:chararray;
B=group A by c1;
dump B;
```

The output is:

```
(a)   
(b)      
(c)      
(ab)      
(abc)
```

Why it has group key order depend on string length but alphabetical order.that way I need to do another key order job ,two jobs total,because there is no comparator plugin for group.

Any solution for group&order  at once? i would much appreciate.

Comment: Actually, Iam now doing it by first padding the string to the same length.  I just curious about why they want to adopt this comparator that differ from original default hadoop experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I find the answer why that, see: [this blog](http://aaron.blog.archive.org/2013/05/27/customizing-pig-for-sort-order-and-line-termination/).
It is an performance optimization trick by pig. Good for only pure group, bad for group into some order, because you can't force Pig to change comparator selection rule.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in your case, Pig uses `NullTupleWritable` for the output key. Since your data is `Tuple`, it will invoke the comparator `DefaultTupleRawComparator`. In this class, it will compare the length at first, then compare the content. Follow this [link](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.pig/pig/0.9.0/org/apache/pig/data/DefaultTuple.java#344) to get details in codes.